# How can I ignore duplicate rows where columns do not contain data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with duplicate rows, however, some of the duplicate rows have columns does not contain data for the same column. How can I remove/ignore only those row where columns are blank? In some instances:

```
Name        Employee#    Location   City
-----------------------------------------
BowerT      48999        NJ Foods  
BowerT      48999        NJ Foods   Pearl
BowerT      48999        NJ Foods   Johns
BowerT      48999        NJ Foods   Johns
```

I'm using with CTE to delete duplicate, however, if 2nd, 3rd, or 4th row has the data I need for that column, I lose it because these are greater than row 1.

```
;With hrEmployee as
(
    Select 
        *, 
        Row_Number () Over (Partition BY Employee_Number order by Employee_Number) As RowNumber
    From 
        [dbo].[hrEmployee] 
    Where 
        Employee_Number = '48999'     
)
Delete hrEmployees 
where RowNumber  > 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure you can use 'WITH' in mysql?

Comment: Why not check the particular column with blank using **where** condition?

Comment: The [mysql] tag is incorrect here. This looks like sql-server.

Comment: Not clear remove / ignore are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an entire example the relevant code change is:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Number ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN ISNULL(City,'') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) as RowNumber
```

What that does is simply ORDER your results of what you want to keep by saying if the City is null or '' (blank) make it last.  You can rank your results anyway you want by specifying different order in your ORDER BY.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10), Employee_Number INT, Location VARCHAR(20), City VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('BowerT',48999,'NJ Foods',NULL)
,('BowerT',48999,'NJ Foods','Pearl')
,('BowerT',48999,'NJ Foods','Johns')
,('BowerT',48999,'NJ Foods','Johns')

SELECT *
FROM
    @Table

;WITH hrEmployee AS (
       SELECT
          *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Number ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN ISNULL(City,'') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             ) as RowNumber
       FROM
          @Table
       where Employee_Number = '48999'
)

DELETE
FROM
    hrEmployee
WHERE
    RowNumber > 1

SELECT *
FROM
    @Table
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that works perfectly. That is exactly what I need.  Thank you so very much!!!